# В SSH доступен только стандартный порт

Tags: ssh

Когда я изменяю стандартный порт в `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` на свой (напр. 44444) и перезапускаю ssh, при попытке подключения я получаю ошибку:

```
connect to host 123.55.45.211 port 44444: Connection refused
```

Но на стандартном 22 порте все работает отлично. UFW выключен. Подскажите как исправить это? Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Вопрос решен. Порты заблокированы провайдером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте с помощью `netstat` на каком порту действительно слушает sshd.

```
netstat -lnp | grep sshd
```

Остановите sshd и запустите его заново. Убедитесь, что он действительно запущен заново.

Проверьте, действительно ли sshd читает этот конфигурационный файл.

```
 strings `which sshd` | grep /etc/
 strace `which sshd` 2>&1 | grep /etc/ssh
```

Comment: Я, если честно, не знаю, что там должно быть, но вот прикрепляю гисты с выводами. 1) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7f46d882e11383ee43db 2) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/57ec9b82ac1280dd6bc3 3) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/efa7ab11578d2972b155

Comment: При вызове через strace надо тоже использовать полный путь, см. исправленную версию; на второй gist нет доступа; в первом видно что sshd слушает 40004, а не 44444